# Nesting API calls in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having difficulty figuring out what is happening (and not happening) in my action creator.

I need to make a call to one API endpoint, get the ids and names of all the items returned, then for each of those ids, make another call. I want to store the return of the last call and the ids/names from the first call in an object and dispatch it.

```
{
  category: name //name of category
  subcategory: [] //array of categories in the category above. 
}
```

Right now, my reducer does end up having what I want, but when I attempt to log that particular prop in the component it is empty. (below I am using OpenSocialAPI or osapi. This is just a basic wrapper for an ajax request. Allows for me to not have to authenticate as it sees I am already authenticated.)

```
export function fetchCategories(id){
  let categories = []
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch(requestCategories(id))
    return osapi.core.get({
      v: "v3",
      href: "/places/" + id + "/places"
    }).execute(function(response) {
      response.content.list.forEach(function(category) {
        osapi.core.get({
          v: "v3",
          href: "/places/" + category.id+ "/categories"
        }).execute(function(response) {
          categories.push({
            category: category.name,
            subcategories: response.content.list.map(category => category.name)
          })
        })
      })

    console.log("Category response: ", categories)
    dispatch(receiveCategories(id, categories))
    })
  }
}
export function receiveCategories(id,array){
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_CATEGORIES,
    id,
    categories: array,
    recievedAt: new Date(Date.now()),
    isFetching: false
  }
}
```

And in my app I am dispatching the action creator in componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesIfNeeded(id))
  }
```

Right now when I console log in my Category component and in the execute above, it is empty. But looking at my state in my logger, when recieveCategories is completed, I have the array of objects I want

```
[{category:..., 
  subcategories:[...]
 },
 {category:..., 
  subcategories:[...]
 }]
```

I suspect this is because of something asynchronous but I'm unsure how to proceed.

I attempted to create my own wrapper for the call that was promise based, but I had similar issues, probably more so because I'm not sure if resolve(response) is what I want.

```
function httpService(path){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          osapi.core.get({
              v: 'v3',
              href: path
          }).execute(function(response, error){
              if(error){
                  return reject(new Error("Error: ", error))
              }
              resolve(response)
          })  
        })
}
export function fetchCategories(spaceId) {
  let categories = []
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestCategories(id))
    return httpService("/places/" + id + "/places")
      .then(function(response) {
        response.content.list.forEach(function(category) {
          fetchSubCategories("/places/" + category.id + "/categories")
            .then(function(response) {
              categories.push({
                category: category.name,
                subcategories: response
              })
            })
        })
        console.log("CATEGORIES: ", categories)
        dispatch(receiveCategories(id, categories))
      })
  }
}
function fetchSubCategories(url){
  return httpService(url)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.content.list.map(category => category.name)
  })
}
```

Can you look at this and give guidance? Also, is me dispatching an array that I built based on the API responses a valid way of doing things or is there someway better? Thank you

I was only able to find 1 other question with similar use case but they are using bluebird or something similar. I'd really like to keep this without anything extra besides Redux.

Comment: You're using redux-thunk, right?

Comment: Yes I am using redux-thunk. My props are being mapped correctly, since I am modifying an action that previously only looked at 1 layer of categories and now requires looking deeper.

Comment: What is this fetching library you're using? It's hard to write code for the correct fix to this without seeing what the `.execute()` API is.

Comment: .execute is just the .then of osapi.

Comment: if possible, you should switch to redux-saga

Comment: I don't want to do any of the redux libraries. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to dispatch your categories *inside* your `.execute()` callback, not outside of it. You're doing `osapi.core.get().execute((response) =>` but then **outside** of that `execute` callback, you dispatch `receiveCategories`, which will execute long before your Promise resolves, and dispatch the empty array you initialize.

You also need to use `Promise.all` to get the response of all of your nested `GET` requests.

There's also no reason to keep a mutating array around.

Comment: Interesting. It is always great to have another set of eyes look at things. I had the dispatch in the outermost execute. Because it is in a loop, the dispatch natural runs the length of the first response. Would I simply wrap Promise.all around the second osapi.core.get()? Also, you mentioned not keeping a mutating array around, you mean the categories array? Do you suggest removing it at end? Or another way to build that reducer array instead of defining one?

Comment: Promise.all takes an array of promises, runs them in parallel, and returns an array containing all the values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all. You don't need to use `forEach` and `push`, just return the final result as a `map` to the data structure you need

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! I'll take a look at it and give it a try.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the execute() api, you may need to "promisify" it to make it play well with promise.all, as in make a promise wrapper that correctly calls resolve() or reject() and follow the standard promise api, not a home grown one

Comment: Was able to do this with Promise.all! Interesting to learn! I had to use an array variable to store the promises. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `osapi.core.get` is some kind of promise based fetch library? And `.execute` is called when the get succeeds?

If so, then what you're missing is that you're not waiting for all asynchronous calls to finish.

I'm going to show a solution based on generic `fetch` and native Promises so you can understand the solution and adopt it based on your specific libraries.

```
const promises = [];
response.content.list.forEach(function(category) {
    const promise = fetch("/places/" + category.id+ "/categories");
    promises.push(promise);
})

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {        
    categories = responses.map(response => ({/* do your object mapping here */}))
    // now you can dispatch with all received categories
    dispatch(receiveCategories(id, categories))
});
```

Also, you're using the same variable in your nested functions - while this may work and the computers may understand it, it makes it super hard for any human to figure out which `response` belongs to which scope. So you may want to take a second look at your variable names as well.

Comment: Yeah, execute called when it succeeds. Thanks for writing this out! I'll take a look at this and Promise.all that was mentioned. Also, I changed the variable names for SO just because they are sensitive, thanks for keeping me honest though! I'll report back in a bit with how things went.

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped you.